# Set locale for JSP page in Openfire

Tags: java, jsp, openfire

I have a plugin for Openfire. There is a JSP page inside it, and I want the locale on this page to be different from the global locale.

I tried this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<%
    String locale = ParamUtils.getParameter(request, "locale");
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fmt:setLocale value="<%=locale%>" scope="session"/>
        <fmt:message key="hello.world"/> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work.

When I switch the global locale, my JSP page shows me right language. But I don't want to change the global locale, I only want to change it for this page.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: "Doesn't work" how? Is there an error message? Is it doing something other than what's expected? What, exactly, is expected?

Comment: Doesn't work in this way: my jsp page uses only global Openfire locale and `fmt:setLocale` does nothing. I just want to use locale from variable `locale` for my page, but not global locale.